# Иконка контекстного меню

Tags: меню, android-sdk, android, java, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить иконку к кнопке. Делаю так:

```
<Button         
    android:id="@+id/contextMenuButton"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view" />
```

Но получаю обычную кнопку без иконки, тогда как хотел бы кнопку, которая бы выглядела, как контекстное меню (та что называется overflow). Вроде бы слышал, что иконка для overflow хранится в android sdk и ее можно получить по такому id:

```
@android:drawable/ic_menu_view
```

Но ничего не выходит. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы кнопка выглядела, как кнопка контекстного меню? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ссылка из ответа: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам надо не кнопку с иконкой, а просто иконку, то используйте **ImageView** вместо **Button**:

```
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/contextMenuButton"        
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view" />
```

Comment: спасибо, кажется то что надо. А можете подсказать, как называется id иконки контекстного меню (та, что overflow) в виде трех квадратных точек? А то в иконке ic_menu_view вообще какой-то глаз изображен

Comment: @JuniorTwo, id не знаю... Я сам с интернетов качал. Гуглить надо "overflow".
Ещё на хабре выкладывали ссыль на архив с новыми иконками.